# Probability of n points on a circle with no points within a certain distance of each other.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Consider the points $P_1,\cdots P_n$ within a circle of radius R. What is the probability that no two points are within $k < R$ of each other?

> One approach to this problem is to draw circles with radius $\frac{d}2$ surrounding the points $P_k$.
>   With this construction, no two circles can have any intersections with each other. This construction will only confirm whether the condition is satisfied, however.
>
> Another approach is to draw $n-1$ circles of radius $d$ around the points, the points satisfying the condition of no two within $d$ of each other. 
>   Next, the probability $P_{n}$ would be $P_{n-1}$ and multiplied by the probability of choosing a point in the uncovered portions. The problem with this approach, however is that after $n=3$, there will be some difficulties in overlap between circles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do your points lie anywhere on the disk with radius $R$ or only exactly on the circle, that is the boundary of the disk?

Comment: @quarague the points lie anywhere on the disk with radius R.